# SPARQL query on rdf:resource with /

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I want to know if I can insert something like this in my Triplestore.

```
PREFIX urlStore: <http://localhost:8888/YYY/HHH/>

INSERT DATA {:yyy :Has_xxx   urlStore:D4/readmmd.txt}
```

The problem is `/`.

Comment: What tools and triplestore are you using?  What error message are you getting?  Such details are key to helping you out...

Comment: Any legal IRI can be used as an IRI in a triple store.  But SPARQL syntax might not let you abbreviate every IRI with every prefix. If you can't put `/` in the suffix following a prefix, then you'd just have to use the long form:  `<http://localhost:8888/YYY/HHH/D4/readmmd.txt>`.